# looking for optimum k-cluster in huge vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have 569 vectors that I want to cluster with K-Means. But first, I need to find the optimal K-Cluster. I tried with the elbow method using the KElbowVizualizer function from the YellowBrick package, but it cannot show me the exact number of K-Clusters. So now I am looking for an alternative for that.

Any idea of how to find the optimal k-cluster?

this is the code I was using with KElbowVisualizer:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

vec = TfidfVectorizer(
      stop_words = 'english',
      use_idf=True
)

vectors_= vec.fit_transform(df1)

model = MiniBatchKMeans()
titleKElbow = "The Optimal K-Cluster with Elbow Method"
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(2,30), metric='silhouette', timings=False, title = titleKElbow, size=(1080, 720))
visualizer.fit(vectors_)
visualizer.show(outpath="G:/My Drive/0. Thesis/Results/kelbow_minibatchkmeans.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain one of my approaches, I know it's time-consuming, but if you need something simple-stupid, here it is:

When I try to find the optimal number of clusters, I just do a for loop between 2 to n, using a different number of centroids in each iteration, fit the model and print the silhouette score.

I select the model with the best score or one of the best scores if there is some specific number of clusters that match with groups in a feature.

Example code:

```
for i in range(2, 30):
    model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=i)
    model.fit(vectors_)
    score = silhouette_score(vectors_, model.labels_)
    print("Number clusters: {}, Silhouette score is {})".format(i, score))
```

It could output something like:

```
Number clusters: 2, Silhouette score is 0.519799469615586)
Number clusters: 3, Silhouette score is 0.6105084877652616)
Number clusters: 4, Silhouette score is 0.6177814923806652)
Number clusters: 5, Silhouette score is 0.623432421353322)
Number clusters: 6, Silhouette score is 0.6454444674454114)
Number clusters: 7, Silhouette score is 0.5614716290406436)
Number clusters: 8, Silhouette score is 0.5585556926568208)
Number clusters: 9, Silhouette score is 0.565265125745878)
......
```

So I would pick 6 clusters.

Comment: I tried it but after 500 vectors, it wouldn't show me anymore Silhouette score

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani could you please post an edit with the new code? Let's see if there is something I can do :)

Comment: I mean, I tried your code above, and it did show me the Silhouette score of every vector. But after the 500 vectors, it wouldn't show me anything. I guess it couldn't be implemented to huge vectors.